# Using a user control as a context menu in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've created a WPF user control that contains some grids, buttons, and sliders.  I'd like to use this control as (or in place of) a context menu in my main application window.  When a user right-clicks the mouse button, I'd like my user control to be displayed, rather than a normal looking context menu with standard menu items.

What's the best approach to take in displaying a user defined WPF control in place of a context menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define the `ControlTemplate` of a `ContextMenu` however you want. Try this:

```
<Window ... xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                        <local:UserControl1 />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.Template>
            </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the control to the `ContextMenu`. For example:

```
<Window>
    <Window.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <local:YourUserControl />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.ContextMenu>
</Window>
```